# Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra Sec 3.4 exercise 3

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on $F^n,$ let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ in the standard ordered basis for $F^n,$ and let $W$ be the subspace of $F^n$ spanned by the column vectors of $A.$ What does $W$ have to do with $T$?

I can see that $W$ will be the range of $T$ since $T(X)=AX=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iA_i,$ where $X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\\vdots \\x_n\end{bmatrix}.$

**Is the author trying to imply something more than this?**

Comment: No, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ is a basis of $F^n$, we know $\{T\epsilon_1,\dots,T\epsilon_n\}$ generate the range of $T$.  But $T\epsilon_i$ equals the $i$-th column vector of $A$.   Thus the column vectors of $A$ generate the range of $T$ (where we identify $F^n$ with $F^{n\times1}$).  We can also conclude that a subset of the columns of $A$ give a basis for the range of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is not understood well (What does $W$ have to do with $T$?).

However, if the relation between $W$ and $T$ is the one that you say: $W$ is the image subspace of the linear application $T$.